# How can I set, get and destroy cookies in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

How can I set, get and destroy cookies in WordPress?

I surfed the web but I can't get clear ideas, please help me find how.

Comment: Sorry, as mentioned in the comment the following isn't good for you:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_setcookie Just use what Phil suggested. Good luck!

Comment: All that does is sets the authentication cookies based User ID. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie

Comment: Be careful, most of the articles out there are doing it wrong, or at least not the WordPress way. Be sure to use the pre-baked cookie constants WordPress offers, check this article out for more info on how to set, get & delete cookies properly https://benmarshall.me/setting-cookies-in-wordpress/

Comment: Sorry about that @clayRay! Had a little hiccup, but should be back up now... and went ahead and updated it since it's more than 4 years old.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can either retrieve and manipulate cookies on the server side using PHP or client side, using JavaScript.

In PHP, you set cookies using [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). Note that this must be done before any output is sent to the browser which can be quite the challenge in Wordpress. You're pretty much limited to some of the early running hooks which you can set via a plugin or theme file (`functions.php` for example), eg

```
add_action('init', function() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie'])) {
        setcookie('my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'));
    }
});
```

Retrieving cookies in PHP is much easier. Simply get them by name from the `$_COOKIE` super global, eg

```
$cookieValue = $_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
```

Unsetting a cookie requires setting one with an expiration date in the past, something like

```
setcookie('my_cookie', null, strtotime('-1 day'));
```

---

For JavaScript, I'd recommend having a look at one of the jQuery cookie plugins (seeing as jQuery is already part of Wordpress). Try http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Also - make sure you are setting the correct domain for your cookies. In the future you may want to have a main domain and a sub-domain both accessing the same cookies. If you set your cookies right now, you won't have to worry about resetting them down the road.

Comment: When setting a cookie in wordpress, I would use some of the constants that are set for it: setcookie( 'my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false ); Without the path and domain, you will be setting a cookie on a page by page basis instead for the site.

Comment: Although it is true that the cookie is best set with an early hook , or like you phrase it `quite the challenge in Wordpress` , there is always the option of setting it later with`AJAX` response.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen back in 2011 when I wrote this answer, I don't think Wordpress had an `AJAX` response option :)

Comment: As far as I know, ajax option in wordpress existed at least since [2008](http://z9.io/2008/11/01/make-your-wordpress-plugin-talk-ajax/) ( when I started using it ) and for sure since [version 2.8](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.8) in some form. But to be clear , the comment intention was not for challenging your answer , It was more for completing it for future reference . :-)

Comment: No working at all

Answer (score 12):

**Try this code inside `function.php` to play with Cookies in WordPress**

**Set a Cookie in WordPress**

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie' );
function my_setcookie() {
setcookie( 'my-name', 'my-value', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN   );
}
```

**Get a Cookie in WordPress**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_getcookie' );
function my_getcookie() {
$alert = isset( $_COOKIE['my-name'] ) ? $_COOKIE['my-name'] : 'not set';
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert')</script>";
}
```

**Delete or Unset a Cookie in WordPress**

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_deletecookie' );
function my_deletecookie() {
setcookie( 'my-name', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To set** the cookie on wordpress I used the $domain value. With it I get to use the cookie value across the entire site.

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;

setcookie("cookie_name", 'cookie_value', 0, '/', $domain);
```

**To unset**

```
setcookie("cookie_name", '', time()-1000, '/');
```