# How can i get the cookie value from header to template pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have set the cookie in header.php like below

```
<?php if($_GET['signup'] == '123' && !isset($_COOKIE['sign'])){
    setcookie("sign", "1", time()+3600);
} ?>
```

now i need to get this cookie value in the page signup.php. but i cant retrive the value in that page. in Signup.php page i am using the below code for check the cookie,

```
<?php
/**
Template Name:  Sign Up
 */
$ck = $_COOKIE['sign'];
echo "cookie".$ck;
if(isset($_COOKIE['sign'])){
    header("Location: https://www.ap.com/app/signup.jsp?signup=123");
}
else
{
    header("Location: https://www.ap.com/app/signup.jsp");
}
?>
```

but it goes to the else condition only (if the cookie is set also). kindly advice...

Comment: You won't be able to set cookies in `header.php`. By then, it's too late. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress

Comment: so i need set the cookie in functions.php right?

Comment: Probably. Wordpress makes it difficult (but not impossible) to set any headers before output starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a plugin and hook with init action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

```
function my_set_cookie() {
    if($_GET['signup'] == '123' && !isset($_COOKIE['sign'])) {
        setcookie("sign", "1", time()+3600);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'my_set_cookie');
```

Comment: if i use above function in functions.php for normal URL(http://www.dev.com/?signup=123) it works.but it wont supports the URL like http://www.dev.com/application/?signup=123.. what is the problem?..the cookies is set.but the condition fails in signup.php

Comment: @Ravichandran does your signup.php in the same domain?