# How to set a cookie in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in wordpress. I have my cookie set like this :

```
<?php setcookie('test', 'test', 0, '/', '/');  ?>
```

in header.php of my theme, but when I go to my browser to view my website I get this error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php:27) in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php on line 201
```

and also my cookie doesnt set. How do I set a cookie in wordpress?

I have also tried this

```
 function set_new_cookie() {
    setcookie('test', 'test', 0, '/', '/');
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie');
```

Comment: In WordPress, you should use `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN`, otherwise you may have issues with the cookies working properly (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665891/870729))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to set them before anything is outputted

look there: [How can I set, get and destroy cookies in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress)

If you are using a theme in function.php

```
function set_new_cookie() {
    //setting your cookies there
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie');
```

<del>Your expiration **date is 0** so you cookies will be deleted right away look at the php doc:</del>

EDIT:
From php.net:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the
>   session (when the browser closes).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You have to set it like this for example :

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

Comment: what is suggested on that will not work, I tried putting in my function.php page but it gave me php errors about the syntax

Comment: it's the right syntax here is more example :http://wptheming.com/2011/04/set-a-cookie-in-wordpress/ what errors do you have?

Comment: I tried your code Jerome also and it did not create my cookie...do i need to call it somewhere? and how?

Comment: you need to set it in the function.php file linked to the theme you are using

Comment: the error is not showing up anymore, and i tried putting that code at the top, bottom, middle of function.php and still nothing, I have updated my question with the code I am using.

Comment: While this answer may have helped the OP, it is not the best answer.  In WP, you should use `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN`, otherwise you will have issues with the cookies working properly (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665891/870729))

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/
>> Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 19):

1. Setting a Cookie:
   The below example will set the cookie that expired for **one hour (60*60 seconds)** since it set with **COOKIEPATH** and **COOKIE_DOMAIN** was defined by WordPress according to your site path and domain.

   ```
   setcookie( 'my-cookie-name', 'my-cookie-value', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
   ```
2. Getting a Cookie:
   Getting a cookie can be done by using variable $_COOKIE which contains an associative array.

   ```
   $myCookie = isset( $_COOKIE['my-cookie-name'] ) ? $_COOKIE['my-cookie-name'] : 'Not Set!!';
   ```
3. Delete or Unset a Cookie: It is same as the above instruction #1, just with a negative time to expire the cookie;

   ```
   setcookie( 'my-cookie-name', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
   ```

Comment: I prefer to use the WordPress constants for time in seconds such as MONTH_IN_SECONDS instead of inputting an integer.