# Wordpress, site redirect using cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have this site below where i'm playing with some Wordpress & php cookies. http://johnnylai.me/lotus

What i want to do is, when the user comes in the first time i want them to choose one of the two links at the frontpage(this is a seperate WP installation). Next time the same user comes back to the site i don't want them to see the frontpage anymore(b 4 the cookie is deleted or expired), i want them to go directly to one the the two sites - http://johnnylai.me/lotus/virksonhed or http://johnnylai.me/lotus/privat - depending on what the clicked at the first time.

I know i need some cookies stuff, but where to put the files and how to do it correctly i'm not sure.

I'm thinking of a sulotion/php code in a file called function.php in the WP installation that have the frontpage(http://johnnylai.me/lotus), but don't know if this is the right way to do it.

Some code example would be nice :)

Any help is appreaciated, thanks!

```
<?php
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie("cat", "/cat1", $expire); 

    // But this is something with categoies in WP, that's not what i need.
?>
```

And also

```
<?php
   function has_auth_cookie()
   {
     // See if cookie is set
     if(isset($_COOKIE['lotus'])){
       // Do nothing
       header('Location: johnnylai.me/lotus/???');
     }
       else
     { 
       // Do Something else 
       header('Location: johnnylai.me/lotus/'); 
     }

   }
   add_action('http://johnnylai.me/lotus/????', 'has_auth_cookie');
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

1. When you're doing header() and you're keeping them onsite you can use local pathing so

   ```
   header('Location: /lotus/');
   ```
2. Because $_COOKIE is an array, when you're checking for a $_COOKIE instead of isset() use

   ```
   if(!empty($_COOKIE['cookiename']))
   ```
3. If for some reason you ever want someone to see the homepage again you'll need to unset the cookie.

   ```
   setcookie ("cookiename", "", time() - 3600);
   ```
4. If the people do not accept cookies they will not be redirected unless you have some other way of recognizing them.
5. In order to set a cookie you have to pass it first. You can't do a header redirect on a page where you're setting a cookie because headers would have already been sent.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
  if(empty($_COOKIE['TestCookie'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['c'])){
      $cVar = $_GET['c'];
      //time to set some cookies
      switch($cVar){
        case '2':
        setcookie("TestCookie", '2');
        echo "Cookie 2 set. Reload the page.";
        break;
            
        default:
         //also covers hacking attempts
            setcookie("TestCookie", '1');
            echo "Cookie 1 set. Reload the page.";  
        }
    
    } else {
    // They're possibly a first time visitor or someone offsite 
    
    echo '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cookie Check</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="?c=1">Set cookie 1</a>
<a href="?c=2">Set cookie 2</a>
</body>
</html>';
    
    }

} else {
    switch($_COOKIE['TestCookie']){
    
    case '2':
    //Send them to location 2
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    break;
    
    default:
    //Send the to location 1
    header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com/');      
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: cpattersonv1

Thank you for your explanation and the code example.

I will see if i can get it to work.

Would it work if i put the php code into function.php and put it into the theme?

Comment: There is another reference for adding cookies specifically to WordPress here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress

Comment: It depends on the theme you're using. You can always try it and see if it breaks, then restore a backup if it does. If it doesn't work you may need to look at the theme to see if something is being triggered prior.

Comment: I would set it as an include myself that way you don't have to worry about losing the code if you update.

Comment: Thanks cpattersonv1.

I'm still not sure where to put each code, but i will give it a try. Yes the first part goes to function.php, but the rest i'm not sure.

Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: There should be documentation within the theme itself if they're using special hooks.