# Wordpress - Custom Variable session/cookie is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some values to the session or cookie in the WordPress site. I am trying to do this in AJAX. But it's not working. Generally my session or cookies variable is not working/creating. I have find the some tutorials and tried that, but still no improvement.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress

http://blog.ginchen.de/en/2008/08/15/session-variablen-in-wordpress/
http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/
http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session
```

I got 500 Internal error when i register_globals off using htaccess and also if i create php.ini file.

Thanks for reading this..

My code in the functions.php

```
function register_session(){
    if( !session_id() )
        session_start();
}
add_action('init','register_session',1);

function enquiry_ajax_request() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['product'])){                
            $_SESSION['product'] = "Some data I need later";
            setcookie('my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'));
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_enquiry_ajax_request', 'enquiry_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_enquiry_ajax_request', 'enquiry_ajax_request' );
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#add-enquiry" ).click(function() {      
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: {
                'action':'enquiry_ajax_request',
                'product' : '<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>'
            },
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is the site 
    http://davidrossfurniture.com/the-collection/product-one/another-chair/

when you click on the Add to enquiry button its calling ajax with the product id, that has to be added in session or cookie. This is what i have to do.

ajax link: 
     http://davidrossfurniture.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=enquiry_ajax_request&product=524

Comment: Please post your own code, which produces 500 error

Comment: My code is not produces 500 error, i got only when i do something with htaccess

Comment: Anyway code is nesessary to understand what are you doing and catch the problem. Post your `.htaccess` too

Comment: code is added please check it

Comment: You don't have to set `register_globals` - it doesn't make sense to superglobals like `$_SESSION`. It is also `off` by default since PHP 4.2.0, deprecated since PHP 5.3.0 and removed in PHP 5.4.0: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: I don't see any problems in `functions.php`. To debug this part ensure that AJAX request is actually made. And please post javascript code sending AJAX request

Comment: I know the ajax is working

Comment: jquery code has added pls check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now AJAX returns session id. Try to debug PHP part, return some actual data to client and dump it to browser console

```
function enquiry_ajax_request() {
    // No need to check $_REQUEST itself - it is always set
    if(isset($_REQUEST['product'])){
        $_SESSION['product'] = "Some data I need later";
        setcookie('my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'));
    }
    $data = array(
        'request'=>$_REQUEST,
        'session'=>$_SESSION,
        'cookie'=>$_COOKIE,
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**UPD:**
Possibly the problem is in **cookie path**. It seems inaccessible outside of `/wp-admin/`. Try to set it to `/` like this:

```
setcookie('my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'), '/');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you check in console the cookie is created for you?. I have updated your code. Its not working. http://davidrossfurniture.com/the-collection/product-one/another-chair/

Comment: Yes, I admit that SESSION var and cookie are set. This is the first response `{"request":{"action":"enquiry_ajax_request","product":"524"},"session":{"product":"Some data I need later"},"cookie":{"PHPSESSID":"2a9778a9b3c0c5bd8699a867a8fead9f","_ga":"GA1.2.192593884.1394088481"}}` (cookie doesn't have effect before second request). And here is the second `{"request":{"action":"enquiry_ajax_request","product":"524"},"session":{"product":"Some data I need later"},"cookie":{"my_cookie1":"some default value","PHPSESSID":"2a9778a9b3c0c5bd8699a867a8fead9f","_ga":"GA1.2.192593884.1394088481"}}`

Comment: i am also seeing it but it destroys when i refresh the page

Comment: Strange, my Firefox saves it. Expiry date is tomorrow and cookie present even after browser restart

Comment: http://davidrossfurniture.com/the-collection/product-one/another-chair/

i am printing the session and cookie check it, its not printing the session and cookie variable

Comment: Did you try to set `/` as cookie path?