# Open ad clicking anywhere in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I have wordpress site and I'm using this script

```
onclick="<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){echo"window.open('http://link', '_blank')"; setcookie("visited", "1", time()+3600*24); header("Refresh:0");} ?>"
```

in body line. So it means I'm using

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onclick="<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){echo"window.open('http://link', '_blank')"; setcookie("visited", "1", time()+3600*24); header("Refresh:0");} ?>">
```

on header.php file of the theme.

But it opens the link in every click.
I want to open it only one time until I refresh the page or open new page.
How can I do it.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the [setcookie function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says:

> cookies must be sent before any output from your script

---

### First solution

You could add this at the very top oh header.php:

```
<?php
$onclick = '';
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    setcookie('visited', '1', time()+3600*24, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    $onclick = 'onclick="window.open(\'http://link\', \'_blank\')"';
}
?>
```

**Update**: I've added the constants `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN` like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress#comment-24258972).

And this for your `body` tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php echo $onclick; ?>>
```

---

### Better solution

The prior solution doesn't ensure the cookie is set before any output sent (there could be some characters in one of you template files before `get_header()` is called, or a plugin could add something).

Instead you should add an action to a Wordpress hook that is always called before any output (like `init`).

So try adding to your functions.php file:

```
add_action('init', 'set_visited_cookie');
function set_visited_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
        setcookie('visited', '1', strtotime('+1 day'), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
```

As for your `body` tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])): ?> onclick="window.open('http://link', '_blank')" <?php endif; ?>>
```

Comment: it's not working again. Again it opens the link every time I click anywhere.

Comment: [check](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajfi) if the cookie is been created in your browser and, if not, try to set a cookie using `setcookie` on an empty PHP file to see if it works