# How to set cookie in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I want to set cookie in wprdpress but its not working.This is my code

```
add_action('init', 'set_new_cookie');
    function set_new_cookie() {
        setcookie('cart_item','some value', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    }
```

but this is not working.
Actually init hook is not working.I am trying to do ajax request here(page visitors are not logged in).

Comment: not working is not very descriptive. Try removing the last argument

Comment: check this out :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress

Comment: there is some changes in question

Comment: the changes raise more questions, what do you mean its an ajax request, is the code above within a function hooked to wp_ajax?

Comment: problem solved. Thank you guys. I was passing array in cookie value.I changed it to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setcookie('cart_item',$carts,time() + (86400*30),'/');
```

Its working fine for me. / at the last is to set cookie for whole site.
Remove / to set cookie for particulat directory only.

Answer (score -1):

Well if this is the sequence your code runs then you need to switch the function and the call to it. Now you are calling the function before you initiated it.

Comment: it not mine, but your answer is wrong, add_action adds a kind of promise to run the function later in the code so it doesnt matter if you define the function after the add action code, just once it's defined before the hook runs in this case init which runs after wp is loaded.