# cookie create with php can't be read in wordpress

Tags: cookies, wordpress

i create a simple cookie

the cookie is there, exists, but i can't read it inside wordpress by a shortcode or a function.

PHP cookie_create.php

```
$data = $_POST['v1'];
setcookie( 'namecookie', $data, time() + 3600);
```

Inside wordpress i try read it

Function.php or in the main file of a plugin.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['namecookie']))
{
  echo "All right";
}
else
{
echo "something is wrong"; 
}
```

no matter what I do, always prints else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finale add "/" to the cookie path, now i can read the cookie in any folder in wordpress

```
setcookie( 'namecookie', $data, time() + 3600, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has it's own cookie functions. Using those could make things simpler: [How can I set, get and destroy cookies in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183162/how-can-i-set-get-and-destroy-cookies-in-wordpress)

Comment: i used this example but i need create the cookie from dynamic way, example: if the user (popup open) insert data inside the form and press the link, this call the ajax function and set the cookie, later or a future visit from the user i need read the cookie and execute a code.