# Check if WordPress password protect cookie exists

Tags: php

With WordPress, if you're using password protected pages, when the user uses a successful password, a cookie is generated looking something like this:

`wp-postpass_299da1fd9cb967a93782c5397fa3a35e`

Is there anyway in PHP to do a check if this cookie exists?

Even just check if a cookie exists which starts with `wp-postpass_`?

Contents of $_COOKIE when I run `var_dump($_COOKIE)`:

```
array(9) {
    ["wordpress_test_cookie"] => string(15)
    "WP Cookie check" 
    ["wp-postpass_299da1fd9cb967a93782c5397fa3a35e"] => string(34)
    "$P$BXtsZ0i1qom3bqiFk4b9GeG8l9dFVG." 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [How can I set, get and destroy cookies in Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6183162/851432)

Comment: @Jomoos Thanks for this, however I don't think it quite answers how I check a portion of the cookie name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)){
    foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val){
        if(strpos($key,'wp-postpass_') === false) {
        //not found
        }else{
        //found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I found a more elegant solution than the accepted answer on [WordPress Developer Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/) to see if the cookie exists:

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) ) {
     //custom code 
}
```

Likewise, if you want to check if the cookie doesn't exist:

```
if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) ) {
    //custom code
}
```

This code is useful for pages that might not have password protection because they are an archive page or what not, but the content it contains may be protected (such as a post).